# JAAS configuration for Managed Identity for Kafka-Connect in Azure

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, azure-eventhub, jaas, azure-managed-identity

Am usig kafka connect to fetch data from evenhub to snowflakes.I need to use Managed identity in Azure to connect evenhub.It fails

Am using below config in json

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER
request.timeout.ms=60000
sasl.login.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required clientId='xxxxxxxxx' clientSecret='xxxxxxxx';
```

Managed identity has data owner role in evenhub
Below command used to start connect
sh connect-distributed.sh ../config/connect-distributed.properties

Am geeting below error

ERROR Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
at [Source: (StringReader); line: 3, column: 2] (org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule:318)
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
at [Source: (StringReader); line: 3, column: 2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:735)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:659)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2005)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:802)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4703)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3076)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.HttpAccessTokenRetriever.parseAccessToken(HttpAccessTokenRetriever.java:286)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.HttpAccessTokenRetriever.retrieve(HttpAccessTokenRetriever.java:183)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler.handleTokenCallback(OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler.java:244)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler.handle(OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler.java:233)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule.identifyToken(OAuthBearerLoginModule.java:316)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule.login(OAuthBearerLoginModule.java:301)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:747)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:672)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:670)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:670)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:581)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.expiring.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin.login(ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin.java:204)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.OAuthBearerRefreshingLogin.login(OAuthBearerRefreshingLogin.java:150)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.(LoginManager.java:62)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:105)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:170)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:524)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:144)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:57)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:97)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:80)
ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:86)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:553)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:144)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:57)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:97)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:80)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: An internal error occurred while retrieving token from callback handler
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:184)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:524)
... 4 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: An internal error occurred while retrieving token from callback handler
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule.identifyToken(OAuthBearerLoginModule.java:319)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule.login(OAuthBearerLoginModule.java:301)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:747)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:672)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:670)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:670)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:581)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.expiring.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin.login(ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin.java:204)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.OAuthBearerRefreshingLogin.login(OAuthBearerRefreshingLogin.java:150)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.(LoginManager.java:62)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:105)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:170)
... 8 more